How can I stub a method before Spring ApplicationReadyEvent?
I have the following components in my application code. On application startup, I want to call some init methods. However, during testing, I want to do nothing when these methods are called.
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
    import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    @Slf4j
    @Service
    public class ManagementService {
        @Autowired
        private Temp temp;
    
        @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
        public void startup() {
            log.info("Startup on application ready.");
            temp.print();
        }
    }
    
    @Slf4j
    @Component
    public class Temp {
        public void print() {
            log.info("Inside temp");
        }
    }

I used @BeforeEach to stub the methods like so:
    @SpringBootTest
    public abstract class SpringIntegrationBaseTest {
        @SpyBean
        protected ManagementService service;
        @SpyBean
        protected Temp temp;
       
    
        @BeforeEach
        public void preventConnection() throws SQLException {
            Mockito.doNothing().when(temp).print();
        }
    }

However, I noticed that the logs from the first unit test shows:
    2024-10-23 10:24:16.675  INFO 23628 [           main] o.a.c.l.i.Jdk14Logger                    : Started ManagementServiceTests in 3.382 seconds (process running for 4.907)
    2024-10-23 10:24:16.694  INFO 23628 [           main] c.c.s.ManagementService                  : Startup on application ready.
    2024-10-23 10:24:16.696  INFO 23628 [           main] c.c.s.Temp                               : Inside temp

and on the second unit test it correctly does nothing for print().
    2024-10-23 10:36:36.799  INFO 17496 [           main] o.a.c.l.i.Jdk14Logger                    : Started RestControllerTest in 0.821 seconds (process running for 5.924)
    2024-10-23 10:36:36.801  INFO 17496 [           main] c.c.s.ManagementService                  : Startup on application ready.

On further inspection, I noticed that the stubbing is only done directly before the test, and when application context initialized, the print() method is still called because the stubbing is not done yet, but on the next test, the previous stubbing is carried over.
I think it would look something like this:

application context initialize --> Event Listener called --> BeforeEach stubbing --> Test

I would like something like this:

??? --> stubbing --> ??? --> Event Listener called --> ??? --> Test

where ??? is any intermediate step
I found that I can use @MockBean to just mock Temp and do nothing for all methods by default, however, during testing I need to use the actual behavior of some methods which is why I would like to use @SpyBean to not have to stub all methods used in testing.
Edit:
I have also tried using a @PostConstruct inside the SpringIntegrationBaseTest like so:
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
    log.info("postconstruct init");
    Mockito.doNothing().when(temp).print();
}

However, this also executes AFTER the event listener annotated method.

I managed to come up with a passable answer (imo). At first my thought process was to delay the EventListener by having the ManagementService listen to some other custom event i.e. StubInjectionComplete.class and have a class listening to ApplicationReadyEvent that will intercept and inject stubs in between, before publishing the above custom event.
However, I decided to just use a simple java class to hold my stubbing that I can just run later and using @TestConfiguration, I inject the injector with stubbing as a callable (runnable is not able to throw checked exceptions):
public class StubInjector {
    private final Callable injected;

    public StubInjector(Callable injected) {
        this.injected = injected;
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        this.injected.call();
    }
}

@TestConfiguration
@Slf4j
public class StubConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public StubInjector getInjector(Temp temp) {
        return new StubInjector(() -> {
            log.info("Injected stubs");
            Mockito.doNothing().when(temp).print();
            return null;
        });
    }
}

And I modified my existing code and unit test like so:
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")  //<--
@Import(StubConfiguration.class)  //<--
public abstract class SpringIntegrationBaseTest {
    ...
}

public class ManagementService {
    @Autowired
    private StubInjector injector;
    ...

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void startup() throws Exception {
        log.info("Startup on application ready.");
        injector.run();  //<--
        ...
    }
    ...
}

@Configuration
public class MiscConfig {
    @Bean
    @Profile("!test")
    public StubInjector stubInjector() {
        return new StubInjector(()-> null);
    }
}

Now, on regular runs, it does nothing besides an extra call to an empty callable, but on unit tests, I inject some stubbing before my regular code is executed on ApplicationReadyEvent.

In this situation, you could use profiles.
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class ManagementService

Note the '!' in front of test to annotate your class with @Profile. This means that this class should only be loaded if the profile isn't "test."
Annotate your test class with @ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class SpringIntegrationBaseTest


I think while your answer is similar to @AyoK's answer on the profiles, your's might actually break my test cases if the class is not loaded during tests and I would likely be unable to autowire and get NPEs. I will confirm this on Monday and get back to you

You can use profiles to control the behavior by creating a method that checks if it is being run in a test environment then in your test properties file define the active profile as test or you can annotate your test class with @ActiveProfiles("test")
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    .
    .
    .
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void startup() {
        if (!isTestEnvironment()) {
            log.info("Startup on application ready.");
            temp.print();
        }
    }

    private boolean isTestEnvironment() {
        return Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains("test");
    }


oh wait, just saw the comments on @ActiveProfiles. My eyes just jumped to the code. I ll have to test it out on Monday before I can confirm anything

Hi, Ayo K. I have just tested your code out, while it technically works, I just found that it is breaking some of my test cases (I am verifying the number of times the method is called), while I can move this active profile check inside the method print() I will wait a bit more to see if there is any other solution that addresses my original wants without changing the source code
